# How to Retrieve All Trips in Strapi API Based on a Many-to-Many Relationship with the Sport Collection?

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am working with Strapi (my API, while the app is built using React), and I have two collections: Sport and Trip. The Sport collection has a single attribute named "Name" and one of the Trip attributes is a relation named sports. These two collections are connected through a many-to-many relationship. I would like to construct a URL that retrieves all trips which contain "Football" as a related sport in Strapi's API.

How should the URL be formatted to achieve this?

I have tried using the following URL, but it didn't work:

```
       GET /trips?[sports][$in]=Football
```

I only get 500 error code. Could someone please provide guidance on the correct URL format to filter trips based on the related sports field?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One approach to accomplish this is by using [] bracket notation as follows:

**In general:**   *strapiapi.com/collection?filters[relation][field][$op]=parameter*,

In this case, `collection` refers to the plural API ID of the collection (e.g., */trips*), `relation` represents the field in the given collection that establishes a relationship with another model (e.g., *[sports]*). Instead of `field`, you should specify the name of a specific attribute from the related collection that you wish to filter by (e.g., *[Name]*). Lastly, you need to provide a value by which you want to filter.

**Specific:**   *yourstrapi.com/trips?filters[sports][Name][$eq]=Football*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).